# How do I find out who added a user?

Tags: security, sudo, logs, accounts

Assuming that someone used `sudo` to add a user, is there an easy way to determine who it was?

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention that they used `sudo`, you'll likely have this in your logs.

For example, with systemd:

```
% sudo useradd foobar
% sudo journalctl /bin/sudo | grep -e useradd -e adduser
Dec 18 22:42:37 gongzuo sudo[24430]:    cdown : TTY=pts/10 ; PWD=/home/cdown ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/useradd foobar
```

On non-systemd systems, you can typically find this log at `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, this varies between systems.  It's not the same on Debian, but from testing on Fedora linux:

"The audit subsystem" is installed and enabled by default.  You can find out even if the user ran useradd from a root shell opened using `sudo -i`.  If you have a persistent systemd-journal they should appear there, and you can see the numeric User ID which audit holds responsible:

> Feb 28 17:30:32 alan-laptop audit[18253]: ADD_GROUP pid=18253 uid=0
>   **auid=1000** ses=9
>   subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
>   msg='op=add-group acct="test" exe="/usr/sbin/useradd"
>   hostname=alan-laptop addr=? terminal=pts/1 res=success' Feb 28
>
> 17:30:32 alan-laptop audit[18253]: ADD_USER pid=18253 uid=0 auid=1000
>   ses=9 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
>   msg='op=add-user id=1003 exe="/usr/sbin/useradd" hostname=alan-laptop
>   addr=? terminal=pts/1 res=success'